# Image type becomes not supported after downloading it

Tags: php, http-headers

I am creating an image compression page in php. I am allowing users to upload their images and users are allowed to set a preferred output type (either jpg or png) and quality between 0 to 100. The image gets compressed using this function

```
function compress_image($source_url,$dest,$quality,$type){
    $info=getimagesize($source_url);
    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') 
        {
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_url);
        }
        elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif')
        {
             $image = imagecreatefromgif($source_url);
        }
        elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') 
        {
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($source_url);
        }
        if($type=="jpg"){
            imagejpeg($image, $dest, $quality);
        }else{
            $quality=$quality/10;
            imagepng($image,$dest,$quality);
        }
            header("Content-Type: application/force-download"); 
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($dest)."\";" ); 
}
```

This is the code that fetched the images and gives it to the compress_image function.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit_form'])){
  foreach($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'] as $key=> $value){  
  $file_name=$_FILES['image_file']['name'][$key];
  $file_type=$_FILES['image_file']['type'][$key];
  $temp_name=$_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'][$key];
  $file_size=$_FILES['image_file']['size'][$key];
  // $quality=$_REQUEST['quality'];
  $quality=50;
  // $type=$_REQUEST['type']==1?"png":"jpg";
  $type="jpg";
  compress_image($temp_name,'./upload/'.$file_name,$quality,$type);
}
}
```

Image is actually getting compressed when I see it in the htdocs/website/upload folder. But when I download the image from that same directory using header function I am getting the error that `it appears that we do not support this format`. That same image is getting opened with same software and also with the reduced size. What do I do to make the image downloadable and useful.

Comment: Image content goes AFTER the headers.

Comment: I did try it but still same problem

Comment: If `$dest` is not `null`, then there is no image sent to the browser.

Comment: I am completely new to the header and their concepts, can you please elaborate?

Comment: Sure I will do that

Comment: Does the function output the file to browser? Or does the function save the file to your file system? Or does it do both?

Comment: I want it to save the file to my system

Comment: Why bother doing this in PHP?  You can do the compression client-side with a canvas.  No need to upload to the server at all.  Just JavaScript.

Comment: By the way, I believe you have some security issues here, as the users can upload stuff to arbitrary names on disk.  Might be able to fetch arbitrary files too, in the cases where PHP can't write but can read.

Comment: Yes it is a good idea to do it in JS but I do want to learn where my fault is in this and yes I have security issues but first my focus is on compressing the file

Answer (score 0):

Two mistakes here:

1. If you're using [imagejpeg()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) and [imagepng()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php) with an actual destination path (`$file` parameter), the functions won't output anything to browser.
2. Header should go before the contents.

Try this:

```php
<?php

function compress_image($source_url, $dest, $quality, $type) {
    $info = getimagesize($source_url);
    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') {
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_url);
    } elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') {
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($source_url);
    } elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') {
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($source_url);
    }
    if ($type == "jpg") {
        imagejpeg($image, $dest, $quality);
    } else {
        $quality = $quality / 10;
        imagepng($image, $dest, $quality);
    }

    // If the file is created successfully and can be opened.
    if (($fh = fopen($dest, 'r')) !== false) {
        header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($dest) . "\";");

        // open the content and stream to browser
        $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
        stream_copy_to_stream($fh, $output);
    } else {
        throw new \Exception('unable to open the file: ' . $dest);
    }
}
```

Comment: Even with this code I am getting the same error that this type of file is not supported. and the file IS PNG. I keep getting this is not a valid bitmat file. The same file is getting opened from my site's upload folder and the downloaded file gives the error